# Jquerymobile: label text is not changing with slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi in my jquery mobile app i am trying to change the label text on moving the JQM slider , in jsfiddle it is working fine , when i try to run on browser nothing is working.
**Below is my code:**

```
<label for="slider">choose:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="0" min="0" max="5"  />
     <label id="sliderlabel">Strongly Agree</label>
```

Below is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#slider").change(function() {
    sVal = $(this).val();

    if(sVal ==1 ) {

        $('#sliderlabel').text('Neither agree nor disagree');
    }   
});
</script>
```

Not sure what wrong i am doing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which jQM version are you using?

Comment: @Omar using jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js

Comment: use `.on("change")` and bind event on `pagecreate` of `#pageID`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3RNA7/

Comment: @Omar hi .on("change") is not working on mobile but Felix answer below is working fine now on mobile

Comment: if you're using jQM 1.4 and jQ 1.9 it should work as in the fiddle `$("#slider").on("change", function () {`.

Comment: all sliders have same ID?

Comment: @Omar as of now they have same id , i need to track all the slider values and send it to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', function() {
    $("#slider").change(function () {
        sVal = $(this).val();

        if (sVal == 1) {

            $('#sliderlabel').text('Neither agree nor disagree');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Elaborate on your answer. _Try this code_ isn't an answer.

Comment: @Felix ..hi what if i have 10 sliders in a page and 5 different pages , do i need to write the above code for all slider?

Comment: @teekib all pages in one file?

Comment: @Omar hi.yes all pages code are in one index.html file

Comment: @teekib I already give you the answer in the fiddle :) Felix most likely wouldn't answer your question.

Comment: @Omar :) did u give the answer in jsfiddle? where?